# "Invalid query type" error while getting Networkadatper configuration through WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to get the networkadtapter configuration such as ipaddress,IPSubnet,WINSPrimaryServer,WINSSecondaryServer by passing the Hostname.

But it throws the following error

**System.Management.ManagementStatus.InvalidQueryType**

The following are the code that i have used

```
query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE DNSHostName='{0}'", objServerInfo.DNSHostName);
                    searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtScope, query);
                    ManagementObjectCollection networkConfigresults = searcher.Get();
                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in networkConfigresults)
                    {
                        NetworkConfig objNetworkConfig = new NetworkConfig();
                        objNetworkConfig.serverId = sysconfig.SystemId;
                        objNetworkConfig.IPAdresss =  queryObj["IPAddress"] != null ? String.Join(",", (string[])queryObj["IPAddress"]) : string.Empty;
                        objNetworkConfig.subnetMask = queryObj["IPSubnet"] != null ? String.Join(",", (string[])queryObj["IPSubnet"]) : string.Empty;
                        objNetworkConfig.primaryDNSServer = Convert.ToString(queryObj["WINSPrimaryServer"]);
                        objNetworkConfig.alternateDNSServer = Convert.ToString(queryObj["WINSSecondaryServer"]);
                        lstNetworkConfig.Add(objNetworkConfig);
                    }
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your query as follows

```
query = new ObjectQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE DNSHostName='{0}'", objServerInfo.DNSHostName));
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! sorry for my oversight